# Removing unnecessary backup files from full backup recovery model

Tags: sql-server, model, backup, recovery

I have started an Microsoft SQL Database with recovery model as FULL. Then the hard drive is almost full with no real data now. I've changed the recovery model as SINGLE and I need to delete those hundreds of GB that full backup added to my Server. Do you have any idea where can I find those logs backup directory in order to delete them? I know that probably the SQL will delete them automatically when will get the new SINGLE recovery model but I am not sure when....

Comment: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/3311/how-to-shrink-the-transaction-log/

Comment: I did that shrink but nothing happen... Still I have only few Kb left on a 200GB SSD server... crazy

Answer (score 0):

Did you take LOG backups during the FULL recovery model? Without LOG backups in FULL recovery the transaction log will be very large.This could be the cause to your space issue.

Switching from FULL recovery model to SIMPLE does not delete old backup files nor reclaims space from LOG. As @Lukasz Szozda suggested, you'll need to shrink the LOG file, but before shrinking, issue a `CHECKPOINT`.

Also in SIMPLE recovery you cannot do point in time restores, but if it's OK for your business, go ahead.

If you need to find the backup file location, this is one way to do it.

```
SELECT  physical_device_name,
        backup_start_date,
        backup_finish_date,
        backup_size/1024.0 AS BackupSizeKB
FROM msdb.dbo.backupset b
JOIN msdb.dbo.backupmediafamily m ON b.media_set_id = m.media_set_id
WHERE database_name = 'Your database name'
ORDER BY backup_finish_date DESC
```

Comment: I found files like *.dmp under Log/polybase/dumb of lots of GB every day... Can I delete them?

Comment: I did the query only master exist because I deleted the previous database due no space available and still every day I have less storage left

Comment: I deleted HUNDREDS OF GBS FROM THE DIRECTORY ABOVE... Today, the system adds 4 more DMP files 420MB each... No database exists and I left only the systemic ones and all of them switched to Single RECOVERY MODE

Comment: Seems like you are using PolyBase, before deleting the files have a look at SQL Server error log to find the source of your errors being generated. Also, have a look to those PolyBase dumps using WinDbg - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/debugger-download-tools. This link may also help https://nielsberglund.com/2019/11/20/fix-polybase-in-sql-server-2019-developers-edition/